# How to make the simon game work properly

Tags: javascript, promise, settimeout, addeventlistener, es6-promise

I'm working on the "Simon Game" project.

I want it to lighten buttons in the proper sequence. But now by far the code works properly until the 2-nd level.

If I am right the `checkButton(randIndexArr, counter)` should be included to the promise, so that if `counter === index` then it should call `checkButton` and maybe there are some more errors that I missed.

Here's a link with the video: How the code should work to be more clear [Zipline: Build a Simon Game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tAPut8a47bA) 
and here is my code:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
'use strict';

var checkOn = document.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]");
var gameCount = document.getElementsByClassName("innerCount")[0];
var startButton = document.getElementById("innerStart");
var strictButton = document.getElementById("strictButton");
var strictInd = document.getElementById("strictIndicator");
var strictMode = false;

var soundArray = document.getElementsByTagName("audio");
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".bigButton");
var buttonArray = [].slice.call(buttons, 0);

checkOn.addEventListener("change", function () {

    if (checkOn.checked) {
        gameCount.innerHTML = "--";
    } else {
        gameCount.innerHTML = "";
    }
});

strictButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    strictMode = !strictMode;
    strictMode ? strictInd.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000" :
        strictInd.style.backgroundColor = "#850000";
});
function getRandArray() {
    var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
        array[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    }
    document.getElementsByClassName("randArray")[0].innerHTML = array;
    return array;
}

startButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var level = 0;
    var randIndexArr = getRandArray();
    playGame(randIndexArr, level);
});
function sleep(time) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, time)
    })

}

function checkButton(randIndexArr, counter) {
    console.log('checkButton');
    var checker = function checker(e) {
            var clickedButtonId = e.target.dataset.sound;
            lightenButton(clickedButtonId);
            sleep(1000);
            for (let index = 0; index <= counter; index++) {
                if (+(clickedButtonId) === randIndexArr[index]) {
                    if (index === counter) {
                        console.log('checking passed - next level :', (counter + 1));
                        counter++;
                        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                            buttonArray[i].removeEventListener("click", checker, false)
                        }
                        playGame(randIndexArr, counter);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ;
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        buttonArray[i].addEventListener("click", checker, false)
    }

}

function playGame(randIndexArr, counter) {

    if (counter === 22) {
        return;
    }
    //Show the level of the Game
    gameCount.innerHTML = counter + 1;
    //Light and play random buttons according to the level
    //Light and play user's input then check if input is correct
    randIndexArr.slice(0, counter + 1).reduce(function (promise, div, index) {
        return promise.then(function () {
            console.log("slice reduce");
            lightenButton(div);
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    resolve("reduce Resolve");
                }, 1000);
            })
        })
    }, Promise.resolve()).then(function (value) {
        console.log(value);
        checkButton(randIndexArr, counter);
    });
}

function lightenButton(id) {
    var lightColorsArr = ["liteGreen", "liteRed", "liteYell", "liteBlue"];
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        soundArray[id].play();
        buttonArray[id].classList.add(lightColorsArr[id]);
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve("lighten");
        }, 500);
    });
    promise.then(function (value) {
        console.log(value);
        buttonArray[id].classList.remove(lightColorsArr[id]);
    });
}

});
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: myDirector;
  src: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Y-Taras/FreeCodeCamp/master/Simon/fonts/myDirector-Bold.otf');
}
#outerCircle {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 560px;
    border: 2px dotted grey;
    position: relative;
}

.bigButton {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    border: solid #464646;
    transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}

#greenButton {
    background-color: rgb(9, 174, 37);
    border-radius: 100% 0 0 0;
    border-width: 20px 10px 10px 20px;
}

.liteGreen#greenButton {
    background-color: #86f999;
}

#redButton {
    background-color: rgb(174, 9, 15);
    border-radius: 0 100% 0 0;
    border-width: 20px 20px 10px 10px;
}

.liteRed#redButton {
    background-color: #f9868a;
}

#yellowButton {
    background-color: rgb(174, 174, 9);
    border-radius: 0 0 0 100%;
    border-width: 10px 10px 20px 20px;
}

.liteYell#yellowButton {
    background-color: #f9f986;
}

#blueButton {
    background-color: rgb(9, 37, 174);
    border-radius: 0 0 100% 0;
    border-width: 10px 20px 20px 10px;
}

.liteBlue#blueButton {
    background-color: #8699f9;
}

div#innerCircle {
    border: 15px solid #464646;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    right: 25%;
    background-color: #c4c7ce;
}

div.additionalBorder {
    margin: 4px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 242px;
    width: 242px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

p#tradeMark {
    margin: auto;
    height: 104px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 68px;
    font-family: myDirector;
    color: #c4c7ce;
    background-color: black;
    border-color: antiquewhite;
    line-height: 162px;
}

span#reg {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.partition {
    height: 6px;
}

.buttons {
    height: 128px;
    border-radius: 0 0 128px 128px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

/* Start and Strict buttons*/

table {
    margin-left: 5px;
}

td {
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

div.innerCount {
    width: 54px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #34000e;
    color: crimson;
    border-radius: 11px;
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 42px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Segment7Standard', italic;
}

button#innerStart {
    width: 27px;
    height: 27px;
    border: 4px solid #404241;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #a50005;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
    cursor: pointer;
}

div.strict {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}

button#strictButton {
    width: 27px;
    height: 27px;
    border: 4px solid #404241;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: yellow;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
    cursor: pointer;
}

div#strictIndicator {
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    background-color: #850000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #5f5f5f;
}

#switcher {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.labels {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin: 4px;
}

/* toggle switch */

.checkbox > input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.checkbox {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #424242;
}

.checkbox > label {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 26px;
    top: 2px;
    right: 2px;
    background-color: #a50005;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox > input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    right: 28px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerCircle">
    <div class="bigButton" id="greenButton" data-sound = "0"  >0
        <audio src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3"></audio>
    </div>
    <div class="bigButton" id="redButton" data-sound = "1">1
        <audio src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound2.mp3" ></audio>
    </div>
    <div class="bigButton" id="yellowButton" data-sound = "2">2
        <audio src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound3.mp3"></audio>
    </div>
    <div class="bigButton" id="blueButton" data-sound = "3">3
        <audio src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound4.mp3"></audio>
    </div>
    <div id="innerCircle">
        <div class="additionalBorder">
            <p id="tradeMark">simon<span id="reg">&reg;</span></p>
            <div class="partition"></div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <table>
                    <tr class="firstRow">
                        <td>
                            <div class="innerCount"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" id="innerStart"></button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="strict">
                                <div id="strictIndicator"></div>
                                <button type="button" id="strictButton"></button>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="labels">
                        <td>
                            <div id="countLabel">COUNT</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div id="startLabel">START</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div id="strictLabel">STRICT</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div id="switcher">
                    <span class="labels">ON</span>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input id="checkMe" type="checkbox">
                        <label for="checkMe"></label>
                    </div>
                    <span class="labels">OFF</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="randArray"></div>
```

Comment: Can you make this code runnable so other users see the problem easily?

Comment: Click the `<>` button in the editor to create a snippet

Comment: JSFiddle works almost the same as the snippet editor. You can add html, JS and CSS, only difference is that you need to import external scripts and css with `<script>` and `<link>` tags - JSFiddle is at least a start but you can easily copy each of the square's code into a snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problem (along many others) is in `checkButton` function itself, where you checking buttons against array, but doesn't check the series of button presses, or "attempts".

For example, if `randIndexArr` contains values `[2,2,1,1...]`, your code is okay with checking `clickeBbuttonId` with value `2` against both array's first two values, and so on.

I did rewrote only one function `checkButton` just to show you one of possible approaches:

```
var currentAttempt = 1

function checkButton(randIndexArr, counter) {
  var checker = function checker(e) {
    var clickedButtonId = e.target.dataset.sound;
      lightenButton(clickedButtonId);

      if (randIndexArr[currentAttempt -1] === +(clickedButtonId)){
        if (currentAttempt - 1 === counter) {
          counter++
          currentAttempt = 1
          for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            buttonArray[i].removeEventListener("click", checker, false)
          }
          playGame(randIndexArr, counter);
        } 
        currentAttempt++ 
        } else {
          currentAttempt = 1
        }
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        buttonArray[i].addEventListener("click", checker, false)
    }
}
```

But to be honest, whole code should be redesigned.

Comment: I just didn't quite catch what you meant ( may be because my English in not good enough ). If you would have begun your answer with phrase "You should remove for (let index = 0; index <= counter; index++) { in you code ", I would understood it more quickly. Thanks for help anyway

Comment: @TarasYaremkiv, we have same native language (well, at least we from same language group for sure), so it's my fault too (since of my bad English). Anyway, if it's helped -- that's good.

Comment: by the way, Do have you any idea why in the snippet editor  if I run code snippet and click button start nothing  is happening? The same issue is on codepen.

Comment: @TarasYaremkiv, can't say about snippet, I have not so much experience with them here yet. But on codepen your code just works, without any modifications: [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qqOjbp) Probably, you need to check your settings in codepen?